# How to version data science projects with large files

Tags: version-control

I am working on a project with large data files (~300MB). I want to version my work along with the data files so that it is always available online. I tried using git-lfs but it has a 1GB/month bandwidth limit, beyond which you're blocked for a month.

What are versioning tools using by data scientists for projects that use >100MB data files (both static and generated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [dvc](https://dvc.org/).  It has data versioning though I do not use that often. I tend to use the makefile (pipeline) features.